React: How to detect the same components
First of all, sorry for my poor English! (translated by DeepL)
MyComponent has some 'state' like a counter and displays it.
In pattern A, when the hiddenFlag is switched, 'state' of the first MyComponent is kept.
In pattern B, when the hiddenFlag is switched, 'state' of the second MyComponent is kept.
In both cases, the number of MyComponent displayed by hiddenFlag is the same.
How does React detect the same components?
Pattern A:
return hiddenFlag ? (
  <div>
    <MyComponent />
  </div>
) : (
  <div>
    <MyComponent />
    <MyComponent />
  </div>
);

Pattern B:
return (
  <div>
    {!hiddenFlag && <MyComponent />}
    <MyComponent />
  </div>
);

I know that React has two phases "the rendering phase" and "the committing phase" when the state of a component changes. The former phase creates a virtual DOM and the latter rewrites the changed location compared to the current DOM.
Does this mean that when the if branch is calculated in the rendering phase of pattern A, it also determines that the first MyComponent is the same one?

I believe both of those patterns would behave the same, I'm not sure "the number of MyComponent displayed does not change depending on the hiddenFlag." translated correctly, you very clearly display one or two components based on the hidden flag. I'm not totally sure what you are asking, what do you want to know?

If those components are counters, Pattern A toggling hidden will reset the counters for both components.  In pattern B, toggling hidden will reset the counter only for the counter that his being hidden/shown.

Wow, interesting, I just worked up a playground and see that in both cases the counters for the "non-hidden" elements do not reset.  There must be some sort of implied key for the elements.  Interestingly if I manually set a key prop on the 2nd  counter in pattern A I can make that be the counter that persists.

@TadhgMcDonald-Jensen
Sorry, that part was translated incorrectly and has been corrected.
What I want to know is how React identifies the same component. In pattern A, the render function is described with a branch, but I don't understand why the state of the first MyComponent is maintained even if the flag is switched. I assume React is determining that they are the same component, but I'm wondering how it is making that determination.

@ScottZ
I'm not having any implementation problems, I know that if I specify the key, the state of the second MyComponent is preserved in pattern A. What I want to know is how React identifies the same component.
What I want to know is what is written in the comment above.

To my knowledge (I may be mistaken) when the key property is not specified - which is what you should do when the order of components can change, see Scott Z's answer - React assumes the order of elements in the list of children will be constant each time.
The statement {!hiddenFlag && <MyComponent />} will either give <MyComponent /> or false depending on the flag, in either case it is seen as the "first" child of the div so the second element that is always the same retains state when the hiddenFlag is toggled.
In the case of
hiddenFlag ? (
  <div>
    <MyComponent/>
  </div>
) : (
  <div>
    <MyComponent />
    <MyComponent/>
  </div>
);

The best react can do is assume the order of elements is the same so the first MyComponent retains the state.

Thank you! It makes sense that it is because false is there!

If you are looking to persist a specific component, you can do so with the key prop.  In the example below, I have created both of your scenarios, and provided keys to the counter elements. By doing so, in scenario A, I am able to tell react that the 2nd Counter is the one I want to persist.


const { useState } = React;

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setCount(p => p + 1)}>{count}</button>;
}

function App(props) {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setHidden(p => !p)}>{ hidden ? "Show" : "Hide" }</button>
      </div>
<div>Scenario A</div>
      {hidden ? (
        <div>
          <Counter key="1"/>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Counter key="3"/>
          <Counter key="1"/>
        </div>
      )}
<div>Scenario B</div>
      <div>
        <Counter key="6"/>
        {hidden || <Counter key="7"/>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



In react the key prop is a reserved prop that every component can have.  It allows react to track & identify a specific component on the page. It must be used with arrays so that react knows which component of the array is being updated.  You should avoid using the array index as the key whenever possible.
Honestly, I'm a bit surprised that scenario A persists a counter when no key prop is provided.  Up until today I would have expected react to treat scenario A as one or two new components.

well from reacts perspective <div> <A/> {cond && <A/>} </div> is indistinguishable from cond ? <div> <A/> <A/></div> : <div> <A/> {false /* could be for unrelated reasons */}</div> and the first case it clearly does represent the same first component each time.
